# .innerHTML displaying [object htmldivelement]

Tags: javascript

Sorry guys I'm really new at this!

I'm looping through an array of people I get back from the server (please ignore the syntax if it's incorrect, it's just an arbitrary example)

```
[{
"group1": [
{
    "name": "Steve Smith";
    "age": "23",
},
{
    "name": "Taylor Smith";
    "age": "28",
}
],
"group2": [
{
    "name": "Henry Thomas";
    "age": "24";
},
{
    "name": "Susan Thomas";
    "age": "22";
}
]
}]
```

So basically I'm looping through these objects and I'm displaying each person in it's own container. I'm taking each "individual person" container and appending 
that to their own "group container" (i.e. one group container will contain all of "group 1" and the other will contain all of "group 2").

On a button press, I used .appendChild to append the correct "group" container but that would just keep adding whichever "group" container I wanted to display to the main container instead of only displaying the one I wanted to look at, which made sense. I tried using mainContainer.innerHTML = group but that displayed [object htmldivelement].

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: If you assign a node to `innerHTML` it's going to call it's `toString` method which is what gives you `[object HTMLDivElement]`. You should post your actual "append" code since that's what's causing the problem.

Comment: @MikeC That makes sense then. When I use "append child" it just adds the the bottom instead of replacing the current displayed group (which also makes sense). So whenever I press the button to display the group in the main container, I'll see "group1" "group1" "group1" if I keep pressing the button to display  group1